# Create a menu bar using ERb in Fire.app

Tags: sass, navigation, erb, compass-sass

I recently started using Handlino's Fire.app with SCSS and ERb pre-processors, and I need a way to build a nav bar that knows what page you're on. Either using `<%= render :partial => "nav" %>`, or just inline html, to give a cue as to what page the user is currently on, such as a class change, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to pass local variables into partials:

```
#on some page
<%= render :partial => "nav", :locals => { :current_page => 'some_page' } %>

#_nav.html.erb
<% if current_page == 'some_page' %>
  I'm on a some page.
<% end %>
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't realise variables could be passed into partials. Best make a note of that...
But I am using `<%=yield%>` to display the pages content, is there any way using that, instead of including the navigation on each page? Else I shall employ your suggested method. thanks.